# modalviewcontroller shows gap after loading

Tags: iphone

Modalviewcontroller is showing gap after loading. Gap is after staus bar which moved modalviewcontroller down and gap shows me main window. So how i can remove this gap which is showing between status bar and modalviewcontroller. There is no interface builder involved. Creating everything programmtically. Help for this will be really appreciated.

```
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];


  - (void)displayModalViewaction: (id) sender 
{

self.viewController = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];  

[navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

  }
```

Thanks

Comment: What type of class is this code in? Is it in a UIViewController?

Comment: yes it is a UIViewController. Found wantsfullsizelayout but that's for view should overlap the status bar.

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see what you are doing wrong. What does your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: implementation looks like? How many other view controllers get created before this one and what does the app flow looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the view frame size [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; fixed the gap between status bar and modal view.

Answer (score 1):

In your _viewController, you need to update this code if you want to hide the gap -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

But ideally it needs to be fixed by-

```
 [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Not sure why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is in a UIViewController you probably want to do something like this.

```
self.viewController = [[[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    [navigationController release];
```

Comment: By adding the view frame size

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
fixed the gap between status bar and modal view.